# PHP para crear y copiar tabla de una bbdd. a una tabla similar en otra bbdd

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, cron

tenemos el siguiente modulo en php, para implantar una tarea CRON donde realizar copia de una tabla en otra bbdd antes de actualizarse mediante otro php, está realizada la conexiones a ambas y funciona correctamente, adjunto los códigos, pero al procesar el PHP mediante tarea cron o ejecutar la sentencia directamente, sin hacer uso de la Cron, también aparece el mismo error.
Las bbdd. están en el mismo servidor y creadas con el mismo dominio.

01.Se produjo un error al CREAR : CREATE command denied to user 'base1'@'172.21.0.73' for table `base2`.`Back_Maestro_BBDD2`

Este es el código php de "conexion2":

```
<?php  
$con2=mysqli_connect("bbdd.dominio.es","base2","@Pass2023") or die ('ERROR de conexion a base 
de datos');
mysqli_select_db($con2,"base2") or die ('Error conectando a la base de datos');
$con2=mysqli_connect("bbdd.dominio.es","base1","@Pass2017") or die ('ERROR de conexion a base 
de datos');
mysqli_select_db($con2,"base1") or die ('Error conectando a la base de datos');
mysqli_query($con2, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysqli_query($con2, "SET NAMES utf8");
?>
```

Y este es parte del código en el CREATE donde se produce el error:

```
    <?php 

    error_reporting(-1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    set_time_limit(0);

    include "conexion2.php"; 
    if ($con2->connect_error) {
         die("Connection fallida: " . $con2->connect_error);
       } 
   mysqli_query($con2,
     "DROP TABLE base2.Back_Maestro_BBDD2");

   mysqli_query($con2,
    "CREATE TABLE base2.Back_Maestro_BBDD2 LIKE base1.Back_Maestro_F20231231")
       or die('01.Se produjo un error al CREAR :   '   .mysqli_error($con2));
```

Comment: El error es de permisos. Revisa que el usuario que usas para realizar el proceso tenga los permisos necesarios en el ámbito de red adecuado. Saludos

Comment: ¿Por qué  hacer DROP-CREATE cuando puedes hacer [`TRUNCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html)?

Comment: El usuario de la BD con el que estás conectando en ese entorno no tiene permiso para crear tablas. Debes otorgarle dicho permiso o bien conectar con otro usuario que sí lo tenga.

Comment: Respondo a vuestras respuestas:
Mauricio Contreras.  Efectivamente es un problema de permisos, y ahí es donde está mi solicitud de ayuda, con el mismo Usuario y en el entorno del mismo Servdor de nuestra web, no permite, mejor dicho cuando intento manejar dos bases de datos diferentes para una sola tarea devuelve el error correspondiente de acceso denegado..

Comment: Sal: hago un Drop, porque diariamente o periódicamente voy a hacer un volcado de una bbdd a otra y la tabla que voy a crear la borro para evitar error si hubiera que relanzar la tarea..

Comment: A.Cedano: si ves la conexión2 al mismo Usuario que realiza la tarea se le da permiso para acceder a las dos bbdd y por lo visto no funciona así. 
Sigo investigando y pidiendo ayuda porque NO es posible manejar tablas de distintas bbdd. y seguro que sepodrá realizar.

Comment: @Kike que puedas iniciar sesion con php a una base de datos, no quiere decir que tengas permiso de escribir en ella, estamos 100% seguros de que en error: **command denied to user** hace referencia de que el usuario se le ha denegado ejecutar el comando CREATE y esto solo ocurre por que no tiene permisos.

Comment: Francisco, estoy de acuerdo,  pero si lo hago sobre una sola base de datos funciona, e error es cuando hago operaciones sobre las dos bases de datos.

Comment: Creas `$con2` y luego la sobre-escribes?.